# Understanding shapes in MRI binary classificaiton keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build my first model that will classify white matter lesions based on MRI images.
The images are 160 volumes 512x513 so a total of 41943040 voxels per image are features and as labels I have my own binary lesions masks with exactly the same shape. Now every time I define a model that is not just simply

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(1, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(160, 512, 512, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I get errors with shape compatibility issues

```
(1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Incompatible shapes: [2,160,512,512,1] vs. [2,158,510,510,3]
     [[{{node binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul}}]]
```

The whole code:

```
import os
import nibabel as nib
import random
import re
import keras
import numpy as np

#########LOADING DATA#########
data_dir = "/Volumes/ms/ML/LD_data_quater"

norm_flair_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'normalized_FLAIR')
mask_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'lesion_masks')

# Load normalized FLAIR images
normalized_FLAIR = []
normalized_FLAIR_order = []
normalized_FLAIR_names = []

for i, filename in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(norm_flair_dir))):
    if filename.endswith('.nii.gz'):
        flair_path = os.path.join(norm_flair_dir, filename)
        try:
            flair_img = nib.load(flair_path)
            flair_data = flair_img.get_fdata()
            normalized_FLAIR.append(flair_data)
            normalized_FLAIR_order.append(i + 1)  # Add the order of the loaded normalized FLAIR file
            normalized_FLAIR_names.append(filename)  # Add the name of the loaded normalized FLAIR file
        except nib.filebasedimages.ImageFileError:
            print(f"Error loading file: {flair_path}")
            continue

# Load masks
masks = []
masks_order = []
masks_names = []

for i, filename in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(mask_dir))):
    if filename.endswith('.nii.gz'):
        mask_path = os.path.join(mask_dir, filename)
        try:
            mask_img = nib.load(mask_path)
            mask_data = mask_img.get_fdata()
            masks.append(mask_data)
            masks_order.append(i + 1)  # Add the order of the loaded mask file
            masks_names.append(filename)  # Add the name of the loaded mask file
        except nib.filebasedimages.ImageFileError:
            print(f"Error loading file: {mask_path}")
            continue
        
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Split the data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(normalized_FLAIR, masks, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Further split the train set into train and validation sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Print the sizes of the splits
print("Train set size:", len(X_train))
print("Validation set size:", len(X_val))
print("Test set size:", len(X_test))


from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, X, y, batch_size, target_shape=(160, 512, 512, 1)):
        self.X = np.array(X)
        self.y = np.array(y)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.target_shape = target_shape

        # Perform any necessary preprocessing on self.X and self.y

        self.X = self.X.reshape((-1,) + self.target_shape)
        self.y = self.y.reshape((-1,) + self.target_shape)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.X) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_X = self.X[index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        # Perform any necessary preprocessing on the batch_X and batch_y

        return batch_X, batch_y

batch_size = 2
train_generator = DataGenerator(X_train, y_train, batch_size)
val_generator = DataGenerator(X_val, y_val, batch_size)

# Get a batch of data
batch_X, batch_y = val_generator.__getitem__(1)  # Specify the index of the batch you want to check

# Check the shapes
print("Batch X shape:", batch_X.shape)
print("Batch y shape:", batch_y.shape)


#model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, ...)

# Create the model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(1, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(160, 512, 512, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


# Assuming you have already defined your model and data generators
# Fit the model using the data generator
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=val_generator)
```

I am a the point where I don't really know what to change. The main goal of this model is to use it for subsequent binary lesion mask generation based on MRI. However, without more complex models it's impossible.

I am sure that the generator produces consistent results when it comes to the shapes of batched data.

Comment: You need `padding=same`